# Three columns 100 percent height css layout

Tags: css, layout, multiple-columns

I am really stuck with the css for this layout. Here is my html code :

```
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="left">
            menu
        </div>
        <div id="middle">
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            sidebar
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want three columns left, middle and right with the width of 25%, 60%, and 15% percent width of the parent and all expand to the 100 percent height of their parent (main).
in the mean time I want the main div to have a minimum height of the browser window and maximum height of its children.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it easily using CSS tables:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.main {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.left, .middle, .right {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.left {
    width: 25%;
}
.middle {
    background-color: beige;
}
.right {
    width: 15%;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/9L8wJ/

To fill the height of the view port, you first need to set `height: 100%` on the html and body elements.

Apply `display: table` to the parent container and set the `height: 100%`, and since this is a table, this value acts as a minimum value, so it will fill the vertical screen unless the content is very long, and in this case, the table height will automatically increase to contain the content.

Add widths to the left and right column, the middle will fill the remainder so no need to do the math.

Finally, apply `display: table-cell` to the three child elements.

You may want to add a wrapper around the content in each table cell is you want better control of the white space between columns, but it depends on you layout and design.