# How to stick footer to bottom of screen and prevent middle section extending below footer?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to set three columns to 100% height of a main content area with a header and footer on the top and bottom.

The desired behavior is:

- When the content does not take up the screen, the footer is at the
  bottom of the screen, and the middle area stretches to fill the middle space.
- When the content takes up more than the screen, the footer is at the
  bottom of the content, not the screen.

I ended up going with the `table` and `table-cell` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24680879/1063287), but the middle section extends below the footer - which causes an unnecessary scrollbar to appear, see:

https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/rqmrxfbp

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515251/holy-grail-layout-with-100-height).

**Relevant HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left_col"></div>
    <div id="main_content"></div>
    <div id="right_col"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#left_col {
    background: orange;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
}

#main_content {
    background: #ff0;
    display: table-cell;
}

#right_col {
    background: green;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 15%;
}

#footer {
    background: #3a3a3a;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: You would have created 3 different column by assigning 100% height to 3 different div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continued on your choice to using `display: table`, where I added the proper markup instead of using anonymous table elements.

In the future one don't know how those might render so I think have them added will make sure they work as intended (and make it easier to read the markup).

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.tbl{
  display:table;
}
.row{
  display:table-row;
}
.row.expanded{
  height: 100%;
}
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
}
.container,
.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.header {
  background: #0099cc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 75px;
}
.menu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  background-color: #999;
  height: 0;
}
.footer {
  background: #3a3a3a;
  height: 75px;
}

#left_col {
  background: orange none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 15%;
}
#main_content {
  background: yellow none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

#right_col {
  background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 15%;
}

ul#main_menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#main_menu li {
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;    /* might need adjustment based on font size */
  width: 20%;
}
#main_menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbl container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell header">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell menu">
      <ul id="main_menu">
        <li><a href="/">one</a></li><li><a href="/two.html">two</a></li><li><a href="/three.html">three</a></li><li><a href="/four.html">four</a></li><li><a href="/five.html">five</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row expanded">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="tbl content">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="left_col" class="cell">
            long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
            long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
            long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
            long content last
          </div>
          <div id="main_content" class="cell"></div>
          <div id="right_col" class="cell"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell footer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

With `flexbox` the markup can be cleaned up a little

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
}
.flex{
  display:flex;
}
.flex.column {
  flex-direction: column
}
.flexitem{
}
.container{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  background: #0099cc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  height: 75px;
}
.menu {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
  border-top: 1px solid #555;
  background-color: #999;
}
.content,
#main_content{
  flex: 1;
}
.footer {
  background: #3a3a3a;
  height: 75px;
}

#left_col {
  background: orange none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 15%;
}
#main_content {
  background: yellow none repeat scroll 0 0;
}

#right_col {
  background: green none repeat scroll 0 0;
  width: 15%;
}

ul#main_menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#main_menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #555;
  width: 20%;
}
#main_menu li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex column container">
  <div class="header">
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul id="main_menu" class="flex">
      <li><a href="/">one</a></li><li><a href="/two.html">two</a></li><li><a href="/three.html">three</a></li><li><a href="/four.html">four</a></li><li><a href="/five.html">five</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="flex content">
    <div id="left_col">
      long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
      long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
      long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>long content <br>
      long content last
    </div>
    <div id="main_content"></div>
    <div id="right_col"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

```
#footer {
background: #3a3a3a;
height: 200px;
width: 100%;
position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: This causes footer to not be at bottom of screen.

Comment: Try the edited one. It keeps footer fix at bottom of page.

Comment: The desired behavior is:  when the content does not take up the screen, the footer is at the bottom of the screen, and when the content takes up more than the screen, the footer is at the bottom of the content.

Comment: Content takes up, you mean when user scroll or what. Because even using position absolute I have achieved the placement of footer at bottom.