# flexbox model not producing 100% height of parent container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Using the following CSS:

```
#menusidebar {
    background-color: #6BC9DB;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

the left hand side sidebar of [this page](http://staging.orsgroup.com.au/EAPportal/index2.html) does not reach the bottom of its parent container `#content-wrap`.

***Update:*** I tried using the flex box model:

```
.flex {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

<div id="content-wrap" class="fluid clearfix flex" data-content="content">
  <aside role="complementary" class="two columns" id="menusidebar">
```

but the child of the flex element `#menusidebar` does not take up all remaining space of the flex parent `#content-wrap`.

[image]

Comment: `100vh` is the height of the browser's viewport, not the parent container.

Comment: Use `100%` to give it parent height .. this assume your parent have a non percent height, and if not, all parents need a percent all the way to the html/body

Comment: Hi @LGSon. I changed the height to `100%` and the sidebar height has reduced from when it was `100vh`. :P

Comment: I also said: _...this assume your parent have a non percent height, and if not, all parents need a percent all the way to the html/body_. This is needed to make it all work when using dynamic height of your site. Most likely `flexbox` is needed, or `display: table` if to target older browsers. One can use `position: absolute` as well though is not recommended

Comment: Here is an answer of mine which shows the structure/css to use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37634823/2827823

Comment: Setting height to `100%` for all parent containers back to html does not work, as I can't have the immediate parent `#content-wrap` being `height: 100%;`. Using `display: table;` does not work. Using `display: flex;` does not work.

Comment: I think my use of `display: flex;` was incorrect. I did not add it to the parent element `#content-wrap`. Trialing that now.

Comment: Okay, and I also see something else, a lot of floats, which most likely is messing things up as you can't/shouldn't mix that with flex (or display table) ... should actually avoid using them for layout ... I recommend getting ride of them and use flexbox if you target newer browsers

Comment: I've removed `float: left;` from the rule `.column, .columns`. Issue remains. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start for you, using your sample link

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/2e1c7wvL/)

where I changed these rules

```
#content-wrap {
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}
.column, .columns {
    display: inline;
    flex: 1;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#menusidebar {background-color: #6BC9DB; margin: 0 0 0 0;}
```

Comment: Thanks LGSon. I made those changes and the problem is solved. However, there is a new problem: `.two.columns {width: 172px;}` is not working any more for `<aside role="complementary" class="two columns" id="menusidebar-blue">`. Neither is `<aside role="complementary" class="three columns" id="sidebar">` & `.three.columns {width: 237px;}`.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you very much LGSon.

Comment: @Steve And don't forget to remove all the "clear float div" markup/css

Answer (score 0):

Stick with the flexbox strategy, as that one is the most forward-thinking. Add the following style to the container:

```
align-items: stretch;
```

And take off any heights set on the child elements (specifically `#menusidebar`).